# How do I extract the return value from a method in the parent component to the child component? (Angular)

Tags: angular, angular-directive, property-binding

I want to use the return value of a method declared in the parent component and assign it to a property in the child component.

**Code for parentcomponent.ts**

```
import { Component,Input } from '@angular/core';
import { AddlistService } from '../addlist.service';
import { TodoComponent } from '../todo/todo.component';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-all',
  templateUrl: './all.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./all.component.css']
})
export class AllComponent {
  @Input() todo:TodoComponent={} as TodoComponent

  // constructor(private listserv:AddlistService){}
   addList(val:string){
  //  this.listserv.addTolist(this.todo)
   return val;
   }
  //  getList(){
  //   return this.listserv.get()
  //  }


 }
```

**Code for parentcomponent.html**
 `<p> <app-todo (addList)="addList($event)"> </app-todo></p>`

**Code for childcomponent.ts**

```
import { Component,Output,EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-todo',
  templateUrl: './todo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./todo.component.css']
})
export class TodoComponent {
  @Output()
  addList: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>()
  task:string=' ';
  constructor(){}
  assignTask(){
    
  }
```

In my **assignTask()** function in **childcomponent.ts**, I want to assign the empty string **task**
to the return value **val** of **addList()** in **parentcomponent.ts**. I am unable to figure out a way to do so.

Comment: So to understand, do you want to send data from parent component to a child component right?

Comment: Yes, the 'val' in particular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to set a property on the child via a ViewChild reference:

```js
// parent
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

import { ChildComponent } from 'wherever';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: `
    <app-child></app-child>
  `
})
export ParentComponent {
  
  @ViewChild(ChildComponent)
  childComponent: ChildComponent;

  addList(val: string): void {
   this.childComponent.val = val;
  }

}

// child
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template: `
    {{ val }}
  `
})
export ParentComponent {
  
  val: string;

}
```

Another way is to use @Input() on the child to accept a value from the parent...

```js
// parent
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: `
    <app-child [val]="val"></app-child>
  `
})
export ParentComponent {
  
  val: string;

  addList(val: string): void {
   this.val = val;
  }

}

// child
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template: `
    {{ val }}
  `
})
export ParentComponent {
  
  @Input()
  val: string;

}
```

Something to keep in mind with @Input is that Angular's change detection only responds when the reference changes, not values. So if you're passing an array or an object, you have to pass a new reference.

Angular documentation on parent/child communication: https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs